# Let $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k$ a power series with radius of convergence $R>0$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

- Show that if the Power Series diverges in $x=R$, then it doesn't uniformly converges in $[0,R]$
- Show that if the Power Series converges in $x=R$, then it does converges uniformly in $[0,R]$

This questions seems to me easy, just to put the concepts in practice, but i really don't got some notions about power series, then i would like to hear from you guys the fundamental concepts to resolve this questions.

Comment: What is there to prove ?It is just a statement of a theorem

Comment: In the first one, of course it doesn't converge uniformly on $[0,R]$ because it doesn't converges at $x=R.$ I think you meant $[0,R).$

Comment: @learnmore What theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Hints: 1. I assume you meant $[0,R)$ in the first problem. Suppose $\sum a_nx^n$ converges uniformly on $[0,R).$ Then the partial sums of $\sum a_nx^n$ are uniformly Cauchy on $[0,R).$ Show that this implies the partial sums of $\sum a_nR^n$ are Cauchy, hence $\sum a_nR^n$ converges, contradiction.

2. Suppose $\sum a_nR^n$ converges. Using summation by parts, show that $\sum a_nx^n$ is uniformly Cauchy on $[0,R].$  See Abel's theorem for inspiration.

Comment: in my exercise, is not $[0,R)$, but $[0,R]$
see: http://www.im.ufrj.br/~gelfert/cursos/2016-2-AnaRea/exercicio-09.pdf
And why could it not be "$[0,R]$??

Comment: Because you're given the series doesn't converge at R!!